# WSO2 identity server email as username + forgot password reset link

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 for authentication. I want to use email as username so i did below change

```
<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>
```

It is working fine as expected.

Then i try to implement forgot password functionality. As per my requirement i need to send email notification with link to the user if he/she forgot the password. On doing this, i have to verify the username and get the key. My username should be example@gmail.com@tenant.com to get the key, but the problem is while calling "`sendRecoveryNotification(username, key, notificationType)`" it is expecting the username as only email without tenant id like "example@gmail.com".

But the actual key generated against the username "`example@gmail.com@tenant.com`" and it is throwing exception like "`javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses`". When i give only email address "`example@gmail.com`" it is throwing "`18001 invalid confirmation code for user: example@gmail.com`".

I don't know where i am missing. Is this problem with WSO2?
The only solution i have is to use javax library directly to send email notification.

Can anyone help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the Identity Server version you are using? You can't directly call sendRecoveryNotification method. You need come through password recovery flow. [1] . [1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recover+with+Notification

Comment: I am using wso2is-5.1.0-beta version. I am following that password recovery flow, it works fine when i have separate username and email not with "<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>" option

Comment: Can you switch to Identity Server 5.1.0 GA release. Also you do not need to set <EnableEmailUserName> to true for tenants.

Comment: Use the username without the tenant domain when you are calling `sendRecoveryNotification(username, key, notificationType)`

You have to set the **Notification.Expire.Time** property which can find in the **/repository/conf/identity/identity­-mgt.properties** file.

If you are using IS-5.1.0 use this [documentation][1] and similar question can be found in [here][2] too.

  [1]: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Password+Recovery
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247607/invalidating-old-reset-password-links-in-wso2-identity-server

Comment: Thanks @SajithAbeywardhana

Comment: @Sathya, is Notification.Expire.Time defined in minutes?